# Azure Data Factory - pipeline runs slow - monitoring

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Azure data factory

Pipeline runs (on debug mode)

Source: MSSQL (CDC enabled)

Target: Snowflake

Each pipeline run is going through a number of activities for each DB and each table that was included in the metadata:

RunLoadCondition    If Condition
LookupCurrentDatetime   Lookup
ChangeCountVarCDC   Set variable
ExtractQueryVarCDC  Set variable
RunLoadCDC  Set variable
GetChangeCountCDC   Lookup
GetTableWatermark   Lookup
VariableGenCTTypeSwitch Switch
GetCTMetadataSwitch

Some runs take a lot more time than it should be (over 10 mins) even though that the table isnt so big.
For example sometimes its because of the LookupCurrentDatetime which takes most of the time.

To look into these Im using the monitor-> pipeline runs. but this is very manual as there arent many filtering options and i need to go in each to analyze.

Got 2 questions:

1. would there be a better monitoring way to filter through the queries that are taking the most time and get their details in an excel ?
2. have anyone encountered this ? any steps that I could take to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would there be a better monitoring way to filter through the queries that are taking the most time and get their details in an excel?

Unfortunately, we cannot get each activities run time for every pipeline in one place through monitor.

To get Activities which are taking more time you have to use `ADF logs`

- Enable Azure Log Analytics for Azure Data Factory
  **ADF monitoring >> Diagnostic settings >> Add diagnostic settings**

[image]

- Configure diagnostic settings

[image]

To begin writing queries and locate persistent Azure Data Factory Activities, you must next locate the Logs option in Azure Data Factory.

**Query Example:**

```
ADFActivityRun  
| where Status == "Succeeded" // Pipeline is succeeded
| where datetime_diff('second', End, Start) > 120 // It took more than 120 minutes to run
```

Comment: This is useful. I managed to figure out that I need to activate those Logs. so only after the logs have been enabled only then I will get some results on my queries? because writing them now and there are no results